# Delete mapping method not working with spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, crud

I am trying to make a delete mapping method with Spring however my code is currently not working. I am quite new to spring so im not sure if I am going about this correctly at all but below is my code:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@DeleteMapping(value = {"/delete/{imageName"})
public String deleteImage(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException{

    userRepository.deleteById();
    return "it worked";

}
```

userRepository is a JPArepository instance. I could use the deleteByID method but that takes an integer and I want to pass in a string for the image name. How could I go about doing this? Below is my DB and the name column is the column that will be used in this api.

[pic of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC3GH.png)

I would like to pass a delete call on postman like `http://localhost:8080/delete/background` and have the 'background' image in the db deleted

Comment: (1) Don't double-include `/delete` in the URL; the verb does that. (2) As I mentioned yesterday, add `deleteByImageName(String)` to your repository interface.

Comment: @johny Share the code for Entity used in UserRepository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your deleteImage method as

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@DeleteMapping(value = {"/{imageName"})
public String deleteImage(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException{

    userRepository.deleteByName();
    return "it worked";

}
```

Then, in your repository interface add a method

```
deleteByName(String name)
```

as your database column is called "name" and I hope your entity field is "name" too. Spring will automatically map it.